# OpenLDAP regex search with shell script

Tags: regex, performance, bash, shell, ldap

For an OpenLDAP database I need to find all users that have a telephone number matching a regex pattern, and are in a given Organizational Unit.

According to this: [LDAP search using regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293231/ldap-search-using-regular-expression) it is impossible by an ldapsearch (what would have been my first choice otherwise).

I would like to do the least possible work on clientside, and querying all users from an organizational unit and filter them by a grep or something similar seems too resource consuming. Is there a better way to do it?

Also I'm not very familiar with shell, so I'm a little afraid of "sed", but I heard it's powerful and performs well in a regex filtering. If I'd need to do the filtering client side which would be the easiest way (not compromising performance)?

And about batched inputs. If I get a lot of partial phone numbers in a CSV file, and each partial number could have the type "prefix"/"postfix"/"regex" (so it's tow coloumns: type, and partialnumber), what would be the best performance-wise?

1. Should I just get all the users in the organization unit and filter them by the shell script (iterating through all the users and trying to match any of the numbers)?
2. Or should I make a query for every number (this is only a viable option if regex filter for attributes is possible in an ldap query).

At my level of knowledge the first one is the way to go but is there a better solution?

I'm using OpenLDAP 2.4.23 it that matters in any way.

Comment: You can only make performance comparisons by making measurements. You have not provided enough information to use to make recommendations regarding how to do the measurements and comparisons. `grep` is for searching, `sed` is for modifying based on the results of a search. It is possible for either to be faster than the other depending on the circumstances.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Performance difference between solving the problem by grep and sed is not the important part of the question, I'm much more interested in querying the ldap with regex.

Answer (score 1):

The results of using regular expressions with LDAP data might not be what you expect. LDAP data is not strings, but specific types of data defined by the schema, and application must always retrieve the schema to learn how to deal with attribute values. The `telephoneNumber` attribute has a specific syntax, and regular expressions may not work. In general, matching rules must be used by LDAP clients to compare and match data sooted in a directory server. In fact, best practices are that applications must alway sure matching rules, not native language comparison operators or regular expressions. For more information, please see [LDAP: Programming Practices](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/10/27/ldap-programming-best-practices/) and [LDAP: Using Matching Rules](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/11/22/matching-rules-comparisons/).